# Google's version of amazon lex

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-voice, amazon-lex

I'm intrigued by Amazon LEX for building a bot but at the same time love the ease of Firebase. Is there a similar product on Google? Maybe accessible via Google Cloud Function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google owns api.ai.  That seems to provide the closest functionality to Lex.  Hopefully that gives you something to look into.

Also, I haven't done this personally, but it seems like an article that might help you:
http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/a-tight-develop-test-loop-for-developing-bots-with-api-ai-the-google-cloud-function-emulator-node-js-and-ngrok

Answer (score 1):

Api.ai supports context based conversations now, which reduces the overhead of handling user context in session parameters. On the other hand in Lex this has to be handled in session. Also, api.ai can be used for both voice and text based conversations (assistant actions can be easily created using api.ai). But Amazon Lex (text) and Alexa (amazon echo) are entirely different. Hopefully in near future both Lex and Alexa will be under one sdk.

**Update**

Amazon has launched its improved beta Alexa skill builder similar to api.ai